Run long running Azure Functions via Logic App using Python
I've been trying to resolve this issue for a while now but I can't seem to find a solution.
So as the title suggests, I'm trying to run a long running action in logic apps via Functions. I have a python code that compares 2 excel files and do a little transformation. It's working fine however, the excel file contains almost 20k rows (It's dynamic and more rows will be added in the future) so it takes a while to finish. The actual Python code runs for around 8 minutes but when I convert the same code to Azure Function, it runs about 11 minutes locally. This obviously will hit the timeout limit for Logic apps. While doing some research I found that using HTTP webhook is the easiest and feasible workaround.
Sample blog I found
https://medium.com/@jeffhollan/calling-long-running-functions-from-logic-apps-6d7ba5044701
The idea is to create 2 functions. One is something that the webhook will invoke, pass a callbackUri and return an immediate 202 response. The second one will execute the long running action and call the callbackuri once done.
All of the sample implementations were using C# or other language and no python sample. I ended up using threads.
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import time
import requests
import threading


app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)


@app.function_name("http_trigger1 ")
@app.route("http_trigger1 ")
def http_trigger1 (req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Webhook request from Logic Apps received.')

    callback_url = req.params.get('callback_url')
    data = req.params.get('data')
    if not callback_url:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            callback_url = req_body.get('callback_url')
            data = req_body.get('data')
            
    if not callback_url:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Enter a valid callback URL",
            status_code=400
        )
        
    try:
        # Immediately return 202 Accepted
        threading.Thread(target=process_and_callback, args=(callback_url, data)).start()
        
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Accepted for processing",
            status_code=202
        )
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'An error occurred: {str(e)}')
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Error occurred while invoking callback",
            status_code=500
        )

def process_and_callback(callback_url: str, data: str) -> None:
    try:

        time.sleep(720)
        

        callback_data = {
            "Subject": data 
        }
        
        # Make callback request
        response = requests.post(callback_url, json=callback_data)
        response.raise_for_status() 

        logging.info(f'Callback successful with status code: {response.status_code}')
    
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f'An error occurred while invoking callback: {str(e)}')

I have a 12 minute sleep to simulate a long running action. This seemed to work and it did bypass the timeout limit in Logic App. However here's the problem, After I replace the sleep with my actual code:

The logic apps intermittently returns the following error:
RequestEntityTooLarge
The request failed with status code '"RequestEntityTooLarge"'.

my request body consists of callbackUri, file1, file2  (both base64 encoded)

Usually once I receive this error, I just 'resubmit' it and it will continue running however, it's stuck (or it appears to be). I haven't seen it finished but It's on a running state for more than 1 hour and 30 minutes (while locally it only takes 11 minutes)

I'm hoping someone can help me with this. Happy to share more information if needed.
Edit:
I should also note that I tested this using a dummy file (file with fewer rows) and using the approach above worked and executed for only 3 minutes. The problem only occurs when working with the actual file.
Edit2:
This a snippet of the actual long running action
        # Read the Excel file 'file1'
    wb_file1 = pd.read_excel(file1)
    column_A = [f"{wb_file1.iloc[i, 7]},{wb_file1.iloc[i, 20]},{wb_file1.iloc[i, 21]}" for i in range(1, len(wb_file1))]

    # Read the Excel file 'file2'
    wb_file2 = pd.read_excel(file2, sheet_name=sheet_name)

    column_a_out = {}
    duplicates = []
    for i, a in enumerate(column_A):
        row_number =  wb_file2.index[(wb_file2.iloc[:, 7].astype(str) + ',' +
                                wb_file2.iloc[:, 20].astype(str) + ',' +
                                wb_file2.iloc[:, 21].astype(str)) == a].tolist()
        if not len(row_number) > 1:
            row = int(row_number[0]) + 2
            column_a = a
            column_f = f"{wb_file1.iloc[i+1, 5]}"
            column_ad = f"{wb_file1.iloc[i+1, 29]}"
            column_af = f"{wb_file1.iloc[i+1, 31]}"
            
            column_a_file1[i+1] = [row, column_a, column_f, column_ad, column_af]
        else:
            duplicates.append(a)

    # Load workbook into openpyxl for manipulation
    wb_file2 = openpyxl.load_workbook(file2)
    sheet_file2 = wb_file2[sheet_name]   
    
    for items in column_a_out:
        row_num, a, f, ad, af = column_a_out[items]
        sheet_file2.cell(row=row_num, column=6, value="" if f == 'nan' else f
        sheet_file2.cell(row=row_num, column=30, value="" if ad == 'nan' else ad
        sheet_file2.cell(row=row_num, column=32, value="" if af == 'nan' else af


are you using Consumption Logic app or Standard logic apps?

Currently I'm using Standard for POC but I'll eventually migrate them to Consumption.

Here are a couple of suggestions. I'd recommend the second one.
1. For your current approach of using two functions
Your two-function approach sounds like you're serialising the Excel files (Base64 in your case) and posting them in the request to the function. I guess the Logic Apps "RequestEntityTooLarge" is caused because you're at the limit of how much you can send. This is a bit of a guess; I don't have any experience of Logic Apps personally.
So instead, write the Excel files somewhere - perhaps simply to a Blob resource. It can then call the long-running function, passing the Blob file names to the function, so it can read them directly from blob. You then avoid the large Base64 strings.
2. Pare it back to a single HTTP Trigger function and try optimising it
20k rows of data really isn't a lot. If it's taking around 10 minutes to run, I'd suggest there's a lot of scope for optimising your algorithm. This might be easier than building a complex interaction of multiple functions and long-running jobs.
Would you consider expanding on your algorithm so people can suggest how to speed it up?

Thank you for your response. I edited my original post to share snippet of my code. So what it's essentially doing is  create a reference number (like an identifier) in file 1 and file 2 then if the reference matches between 2 files,  then copy some contents from file 1 to file 2. e.g both A5 from file1 == A189 in file2, then I want F5 from file 1 to be the value of F189. Hopefully that makes sense.
This is I think the 3rd version as I was trying to optimize it further. This approach is kind of doing "search" to identify the row number and use that row number to update the excel.

So yes, I'm pretty sure you can optimise that. You're checking duplicates by taking each of the 20k rows, and looking through each of the other 20k rows, so 400,000,000 comparisons. I'm not a Python dev so I can't recommend syntax, I'm sure there'll be a way to either create a Dictionary (so it's 1 lookup per row, instead of 20k); or even to do something more sophistcated like a join between the two datasets. Either way - I stand by my answer that you should ditch the complicated two-function approach, and just optimise a single one.
